# Adding far future Expires header to .ttf and .otf files

Tags: .htaccess, header

```
AddType font/opentype .otf
AddType font/truetype .ttf
AddType font/ie .eot
<FilesMatch "\.(otf|eot|ttf|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm trying to add far future Expires header to my font files. This is what I have in my .htaccess file but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for other files like CSS/gif/png? If not then you probably don't have permissions to change the headers through `.htaccess`. If you have access to the server you can put the same code in your `httpd.conf` file, otherwise ask your host to do it or give you more permissions in `.htaccess` files.

If it does work for other files maybe try renoving the `AddType` directives to see if that works, or moving those directives below the setting of the headers.